# Converting array of java objects into JavaScript array

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I'm writing a GWT application and I need to pass an array of java objects into JavaScript (or convert such array to JS array), I'm very new to JSNI and wondering if it's possible to do.
For example :

```
public class EntityBase {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    public EntityBase(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and I have an array of such objects...can I pass them correctly? If not, what will you suggest me to do? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to encode and decode objects.

As alternative, you can use [AutoBeans](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean).

I use AutoBean, but GSON may have less overhead for you. You may need to add a Default Constructor (without parameter) and get/set Methods.

Comment: Thanks for advice to use GSON, it was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Note that you cannot use GSON on the client side of GWT.

Comment: At clientside I would use AutoBeans

Answer (score 0):

You might try using **GWT Overlay concepts** with **Lightweight collections**

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay

Example - http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.in/2008/08/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-2.html